# crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a django application. In the application there exists a contribution form. I created the form with django models and django forms. But when I try to run the application, I get the following error.

```
crispy_forms.exceptions.CrispyError: |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

## django models.py

```
CONTRIBUTE_CHOICE = (
    ('Books', 'Books'),
    ('Renovation', 'Renovation'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )

class Contribute(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contribution = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CONTRIBUTE_CHOICE)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName
```

## django forms.py

```
from .models import Contribute

CONTRIBUTE_CHOICE = (
    ('Books', 'Books'),
    ('Renovation', 'Renovation'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )

class ContributeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    contribution = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONTRIBUTE_CHOICE, required=True )

    class Meta:
        model = Contribute

        widgets = {
            'firstName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'lastName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
        }
        fields = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'contribution')
```

## django views.py

```
from .forms import ContributeForm

def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        contributeForm = ContributeForm(request.POST)

        if contributeForm.is_valid():
            post = contributeForm.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        contributeForm = ContributeForm()
        context = {'contributeForm': contributeForm}
        return render(request, 'donate.html', context)
```

## donate.html tempate

```
<form class='contribution_form' method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ contributeForm.firstName|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{ contributeForm.lastName|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ contributeForm.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ contributeForm.contribution|as_crispy_field }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[This](http://gregblogs.com/the-little-things-tlt-django-creating-a-drop-down-list-with-django/) is the link I followed to create the form

## [EDIT-1]

I changed the code as per the answer and now I get the following error. Please help me

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'as_crispy_field'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't pass your form to the donate.html tempate:

```
def donate(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
       contributeForm = ContributeForm(request.POST)

       if contributeForm.is_valid():
          post = contributeForm.save(commit=False)
          post.save()
          return redirect('home')
       else:
       # this should be include if form validate failed
          return render(request, 'donate.html', {'contributeForm': contributeForm})

  elif request.method == "GET":
       contributeForm = ContributeForm()
       context = {'contributeForm': contributeForm}
       # return render(request, 'index.html', context) <-- why do you have this here?
       return render(request, 'donate.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi! I copied the index view for the donate view. Forgot to change the reder part of the code. I made the chage and got rid of that error. Now I am getting this error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'as_crispy_field'` I have also edited the question

Comment: from [this](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/96) you need to load the crispy form first in the template  with `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` on top of your template

Comment: i'm glad it help you

Answer (score 1):

Your form is name is:

> ContributeForm

and in the template you writed as:

> contributeForm

is keysensitive that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. It was a variable / form field of type ForeignKey, which should present choices, that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the field in the update view?
Like the following

```
fields = [
    'field_1',
    'field_2',
]
```

If you have forgotten to add **field_3** it will raise an error.